# SSIS when using getdate is there a way to remove miliseconds?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to ssis. I'd say an intermediate beginner :)

Is there a way to remove miliseconds from getdate()?

I.e. if the getdate() function returned

> 2018-10-10 18:31:45.924000

, I'd want to remove the

> .924000

.

Edit:

I will be including this in the file name at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data always comes in this format:

yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS

Instead of trying to remove the miliseconds, I just grabbed the first 19 characters with the left function.

Problem solved.

Edit:

Here is the expression that I used:

```
left((DT_WSTR, 4000) GETDATE(),19)
```

Comment: Problem introduced - you converted a completely legitimate date to a string.

Comment: I'm going to append this value as a file name.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. In this situation is certainly a valid approach to convert it to a string.

Comment: Fixed my original post.

Comment: Once you post the actual expression you used, you should be able to accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that preserves the date data type

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2(0))
```

I'm not sure what datatype this is reported as in SSIS. You might need to cast it back to datetime to keep it happy

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2(0)) AS DATETIME)
```